# Flutter how to use in_app_purchase plugin to implement subsciptions?

Tags: flutter

I'm using the in_app_purchase (https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase) Flutter plugin to implement subscription.

I fail to understand how to check if a certain user is still subscribed:
The queryPastPurchases method returns a PurchaseDetails object per subscription but I can't find a "status" for the current subscription (active / non active etc.)...

I can check the transactionDate field but it isn't a good solution.

Appriciate any help with this issue

Comment: You'll probably find this answer helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57474549/check-subscription-validity-using-flutters-in-app-purchase-plugin

Answer (score -2):

Loop through each PurchaseDetails, and if a **purchase.billingClientPurchase.sku** == **"your_subscriptionID"** then an active subscription exists.
If the user cancels the subscription and it has past the ending period(30 days), then ***response.pastPurchases list*** will not contain a subscription/purchase of **"your_subscriptionID"**.

```
for (PurchaseDetails purchase in response.pastPurchases) {

    if(purchase.billingClientPurchase.sku == "your_subscriptionID"){
      hasSubscription = true;
    }

    if (Platform.isIOS) {
      InAppPurchaseConnection.instance.completePurchase(purchase);
    }
  }
```