# How to check if a user have a active subscription using in_app_purchase

Tags: flutter, dart, in-app-purchase, in-app-subscription

I am using in_app_purchase, version 3.1.7 in flutter.
And the purchases for subscription works well. But their is no documentation on how I can check if the current user have an active subscription.

I have tried to make this code but I am missing something:

```
  Future<void> loadSubscriptions() async {
    final Set<String> subscriptionIds = <String>{'premium'};
    final ProductDetailsResponse response =
        await _inAppPurchase.queryProductDetails(subscriptionIds);
    final List<ProductDetails> subscriptions = response.productDetails;
    print(subscriptions);
  }

  void _listenToPurchaseUpdateV1(
      List<PurchaseDetails> purchaseDetailsList) async {
    purchaseDetailsList.forEach((PurchaseDetails purchaseDetails) async {
      if (purchaseDetails.status == PurchaseStatus.purchased) {
        if (purchaseDetails.pendingCompletePurchase == true) {
          _isSubscribed = true;
        } else {
          _isSubscribed = false;
        }
      } else if (purchaseDetails.status == PurchaseStatus.error) {
        print("ERROR ERROR");
      }
    });
  }

  Future<void> checkSubscriptionStatus() async {
    var app = _inAppPurchase.purchaseStream;
    app.listen(_listenToPurchaseUpdateV1, onDone: () {
      setState(() {
        _isSubscribed;
      });
    });
  }
```

I was looking in another thread for answers but did not find any. Was checking this one:
[Flutter how to use in_app_purchase plugin to implement subsciptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57164366/flutter-how-to-use-in-app-purchase-plugin-to-implement-subsciptions)

Answer (score -1):

According to the plugin's example [code](https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase/example):

> ```
> // NOTE: If you are making a subscription purchase/upgrade/downgrade, we recommend you to
> // verify the latest status of you your subscription by using server side receipt validation
> // and update the UI accordingly. The subscription purchase status shown
> // inside the app may not be accurate.
> ```

**Solution**: Shift your purchase management logic to a **backend**. Here is why:

## Understanding the limitations of in_app_purchase plugin

### Purpose of `in_app_purchase` plugin:

The [`in_app_purchase`](https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase) plugin primarily facilitates communication with the billing API and the process of making purchases. However, it does not inherently handle the storage, management or validation of user purchase data.

### Server requirement for subscription validation:

To efficiently check the status of a user's subscription, it's crucial to have a server-side component. This server acts as a centralized hub where user purchase data is securely stored and managed.

When a user makes a purchase, the server should receive and store the relevant data, including the purchase token and user identifier and also verify the purchase. Subsequently, the app can communicate with the server to verify the current subscription status.

Using a server ensures the integrity and security of user subscription data. Storing this information on the client-side alone might expose it to potential vulnerabilities and fraud.

##### Handling different platforms:

Operating systems and platforms might have distinct requirements and methods for subscription validation. A server can act as a unified solution, allowing seamless integration with various platforms.

##### Scalability and maintenance:

In scenarios where multiple users are involved, a server provides scalability. Additionally, maintaining and updating subscription-related logic centrally on the server is more efficient than managing it within the app.

##### Consideration for future enhancements:

Having a server-side infrastructure allows for future enhancements and modifications to the subscription validation process without requiring updates to the client-side application.

##### Enhancing user experience:

A well-implemented server-side solution contributes to a smoother and more reliable user experience by ensuring accurate and up-to-date subscription information.

### Implementation:

One possible solution would be using [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com) as your backend. There is also a [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-in-app-purchases) by Google that demonstrates the integration of the plugin.

### Conclusion:

In summary, while the `in_app_purchase` plugin is instrumental for initiating purchases, a robust subscription verification system necessitates the incorporation of a server-side component for secure data management and validation.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Both Android and Apple stores act as front ends to sell subscriptions and renewals.  They provide native APIs (not backends) to check for an active subscription.  Thus an app must have an available method via in-app-purchase plUGIN TO CHECK FOR AN ACTIVE SUBSCRIPTION.